# What compatibility issues might be expected when using the MegaCoin wallet on Wine?

Tags: wallet, ubuntu, linux, dogecoin

Installing a wallet under linux is sometimes difficult without an up-to-date tutorial for users who are not familiar with linux.

I found that it is pretty easy to install [wine](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) on Ubuntu 12.04.4 instead and then installing the windows wallet.

I have been using this approach for Megacoin, Darkcoin, and Dogecoin for a month now and have not met any issues so far.

I am still wondering, whether one should expect negative consequences or compatibility issues when running wallets through wine?